# How can i preserve CDATA when loading with DOMDocument.loadHTML?

Tags: php, domdocument, cdata

when loading a string with CDATA with DOMDocument.loadHTML() and then saving it with DOMDocument.saveXML() all the CDATA-nodes are lost - how can they be preserved?

```
<?php
$html = ''
    . '<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . "\n"
    . '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">' . "\n" 
    . '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">' . "\n" 
    . '<head>' . "\n" 
    . '<title>TEST</title>' . "\n" 
    . '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml; charset=utf-8"/>' . "\n" 
    . '</head>' . "\n" 
    . '<body>' . "\n" 
    . '<p>' . "\n" 
    . 'TEST: ' . "\n" 
    . '<![CDATA[SHOW ME!]]>' . "\n" 
    . '</body>' . "\n" 
    . '</html>' . "\n" 
    ;
$DOM = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$xml = $DOM->saveXML();
echo nl2br(htmlentities($xml));
?>
```